# Reload div without reloading entire page not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, refresh, reload

I'm working with Java Portlets and Websphereportal

I have a page with a profile picture that you can delete or change,
In the part of the page I have two divs in my JSP file:

```
<div id="fotoDefault" style="display: none"> 
<img name="Fotografia" src="/wps/themes/html/experis_v1/images/foto_Placeholder.png"     width="200" height="200" alt="Tu Fotografía tamaño 200 X 200" style="background-color:     #000000">
</div>                  
<div id="fotoReal" style="display: none">
<img name="Fotografia" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/fotoServlet" width="200"      height="200" alt="Tu Fotografía tamaño 200 X 200" style="background-color: #000000">
</div>
```

fotoDefault is an image that shows that you can upload a picture in some size and some format

fotoReal shows a picture when you have upload a picture

My problem is that when I tried to upload a picture, I can't see the new picture unless I do a page refresh and the client doesn't like that blink.

I've been trying to do this with JQuery/Ajax but with no success, somethink like this at the end of my $(document).ready(function(){   :

```
var url2 = location.href;
$('#fotoReal').load(url2);
```

but it doesn't refresh that div, as I was expecting

What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestion?

Thanks! ^^

Ralex

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a few things wrong.

1) The code you put in your $(document).ready(...) will only be executed once when the page loads.

2) The location.href you are calling "load" on is the current page which means it will return the whole page not refresh the picture.

Comment: Thanks, I tried:

$('#fotoReal').load(url2 + "#fotoReal");
with the same result

Then, with an space after the url

$('#fotoReal').load(url2 + " #fotoReal");
but it disapear, not reaload, then I notices in the page source that I have something similar to this

<div id="fotoReal" style="display :block">
     <div id="fotoReal" style="display: none">
         <img....>
     </div>
</div>
it didn't replace the div, but add an other identical as it was when the page load (with display: none)

I add a

document.getElementById('fotoReal').style.display = 'block';
at the end and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Ralexrdz - $(SELECTOR).load(URL) will put whatever content is at the URL you give it inside of the element SELECTOR (whether its a DIV or P or whatever). The URL you are giving the load() function needs to return the IMG html if that's what you want inside the DIV.